# Pandas - issue with numpy.where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following line of code:

```
# slice off the last 4 chars in name wherever its code contains the substring '-CUT'
df['name'] = np.where(df['code'].str.contains('-CUT'),
                      df['name'].str[:-4], df['name'])
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working correctly. It's slicing off the last 4 characters for the correct columns, but it's also doing it for rows where the code is None/empty (almost all instances).

Is there anything obviously wrong with how I'm using np.where?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### np.where

You can specify `regex=False` and `na=False` as parameters to [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) so that only rows where your condition is met are updated:

```
df['name'] = np.where(df['code'].str.contains('-CUT', regex=False, na=False),
                      df['name'].str[:-4], df['name'])
```

`regex=False` isn't strictly necessary for this criterion, but it should improve performance. `na=False` ensures any type which cannot be processed via `str` methods returns `False`.

#### pd.DataFrame.loc

Alternatively, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). This seems more natural than specifying an "unchanged" series as a final argument to `np.where`:

```
mask = df['code'].str.contains('-CUT', regex=False, na=False)
df.loc[mask, 'name'] = df['name'].str[:-4]
```

Comment: I don't believe the `regex` has an impact.  Nothing in the matching pattern `'-CUT'` that should cause a problem.  Also, `np.where` should evaluate `None` as `False` and therefore `na=False` will also not have an impact.  The problem must be in the data or a typo in the code.  The act of copying and pasting this code may have solved the problem.

Comment: @piRSquared, On the `regex` part I agree, but in the *general* case (e.g. `|`) it can have an impact. (Aside, `regex=False` is also more efficient.) I often see different types fail unless you put `na=False`; I thought that was the main purpose? Guess we'll never know until we see data :(

Comment: Yeah!  I  see that.  `na=False` is necessary for `np.nan` but not for `None`.  Well you had my upvote already (-:  I was able to recreate with toy data that included both `None` and `np.nan`.  It truncated strings where `code` was `np.nan`.  Reminding me that Numpy evaluates `np.nan` as `True` and `None` as `False`.  When you use `na=False` you solve this problem.

Comment: Might also be able to use: `df['name'].where(~df['name'].str.contains('-CUT'), df['name'].str[:-4], inplace=True)` I think...

Comment: @JonClements you still need to use `na=False` for the reasons I (edited) mentioned above.  Actually, you need it to ensure `where` doesn't fail.  It will choke unless the conditional series is all boolean.

Comment: @piRSquared ahh good point on the fill value.... was just pointing out that `pd.Series.where` is an option always.

Comment: @JonClements, or how about `pd.DataFrame.mask` so we don't even have to negate the series.

Comment: You mean like @piRSquared had? :)

Comment: @JonClements, Yes, good he's undeleted. I've removed it from mine :)

Comment: fwiw, I got 'ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis' when trying the mask solution. I'm sure it'd work under normal circumstances but unfortunately the dataset I'm dealing with is kind of bad (which I can't change since it's not my data)

Comment: @JesusMonroe, I think you have duplicate column names. Obviously this will confuse Pandas and won't work. You need to clean this up first.

Comment: There are no duplicate column names

Comment: @JesusMonroe, Not sure then, you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: The first solution worked, so I'm fine with that. I don't need mask to work, I was mostly just informing in case someone gets the same thing in the future